# Example of neural network in keras that inputs and outputs an image

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, keras, convolution

Can please somebody present me with a (preferably Keras) model that inputs and outputs an image. Let's say for example a network that gets for input a color image and outputs a black and white image. Or for example a network that inputs edges of a painting image and outputs fully colored image.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Autoencoders** are example of big class of networks that output something similar to input.

You can find example autoencoders ran on MNIST dataset on [Keras Blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).